# Cant understand what this refers to

Tags: javascript

Can anybody elaborate below in `innerF`, what does `this` refer to? `User` or `innerF`?

```
function User(){
  this.id = 1;
};

User.prototype.sayHi = function(){
    var innerF = function(){
        this.id = 2; // "this" refers to User or innerF ?
    };

    return innerF;
};
```

Also does the `new` keyword or *anonymous* function has to do with changing reference of `this` keyword?

What if I call it all like this:

```
var u = User;
var f = u.sayHi();
f();
```

Or

```
var u = new User;
var f = u.sayHi();
f();
```

Thanks

Comment: @Topener: I don't know how to try that, learning JS :)

Comment: @Topener: Seems like I managed to call it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What the `this` local refers to inside of `innerF` will depend on how the function is eventually invoked.  It can be invoked in a variety of ways that will change the meaning of `this`.  For example

```
var u = new User();
var innerF = u.sayHi();
innerF();              // 'this' is window
innerF.call(u);        // 'this' is 'u'
innerF.call("hello");  // 'this' is "hello"
```

Based on your code though it appears that you want `this` to refer to the instance of `User` on which `sayHi` was invoked.  If so then you need to store `this` in a local and refer to that local within `innerF`.

```
User.prototype.sayHi = function(){
    var self = this;
    var innerF = function(){
        self.id = 2; 
    };

    return innerF;
};
```

Note though that `this` inside `sayHi` isn't guaranteed to point to `User` instance either.  In general it will the same tricks can be done to `sayHi` that were done to `innerF`.  For example

```
var sayHi = u.sayHi;
sayHi();   // 'this' is window
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to make `this` refer to `innerF`, I have also provided code to run it.

Comment: @Dev555: You want `this` refer to the function itself? Why don't you use `innerF.id = ...` then instead of `this`?

Comment: @Dev555 If you want `this` to refer to something specific, you have to bind it to that explicitly using `call()` (as this answer shows) or [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 2):

You're not calling the function in that code, so it doesn't refer to anything yet.

The value of `this` is determined when you *call* the function, not define it (unless you use something like `bind`).

Comment: Can you elaborate how calling affects reference of `this` ? With code. Thanks

Comment: @Dev555: Do some research, read some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Answer (score 1):

```
var u = User;
var f = u.sayHi();
f();
```

The code above will throw error. `User` is a function, not a `User` object, so it doesn't have the method `sayHi`, so you will get error of below.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function User(){
  this.id = 1;
} has no method 'sayHi'
```

---

```
var u = new User;
var f = u.sayHi();
f();
```

The code above will not throw error, and `u` is an object of `User`, ([how new works<sup>from mdn</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new)), and it's method `sayHi` return a function, and you execute the function by `f();`, so the `this` inside of the function is refer the current context when the function be called. So if your code is in global scope, the `this` is referring the `window` object.

And you could set the context by `f.call(u);`, then the `this` is referring the object `u`, and you changed the User object `u`'s id to 2.